# Angular 6 Testing - Pipe that uses another custom service

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-test

I have a custom pipe that has a reference to another custom service in its constructor and uses a method from this service:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { CodeService } from "../Services/code.service";

@Pipe({ name: "codePipe" })
export class CodePipe implements PipeTransform {
    codes: { [key: number]: any } = {};

    constructor(readonly codeService: CodeService) {
        this.getCodesFromService();
    }

    transform(index: number){
        return this.codes[index];
    }

    getCodesFromService() {
        this.codeService.getCodes().subscribe(data => {
            this.codes = data.reduce(
                (codes, code) => {
                    codes[code.index] = code.code;
                    return codes;
                }, {});
        });
    }
}
```

I want to set up a simple test for the pipe like this:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { CodePipe } from "./code.pipe";
import { CodeService } from "../Services/code.service";
import { MockCodeService } from "../Mocks/mock.code.service";

describe("code.pipe", () => {
    let pipe;

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            CodePipe,
            { provide: CodeService, useClass: MockCodeService}
        ]
    }));

    beforeEach(inject([CodePipe], p => pipe = p ));

    it("should return correct values", () => {
        expect(pipe.transform(0)).toBe("-");
    });
});
```

The mock service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class MockCodeService {
    getCodes(): Observable<string[]> {
        const result = [
            {index: 0, code: "-"}
        ];

        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            observer.next(result);
            observer.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

When running the test an error is thrown in afterAll:

```
{
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown"
}
```

Why doesn't the test succeed? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the mock service ?

Comment: Updated question, by adding mock service

Comment: Are you sure the error is from this test ? I see not problems in the updated code and would expect it works like it is.

Comment: Yes I am sure, the error came after I added this particular test file. If I comment out the test, the test run succeeds 100%.

Comment: Maybe it's something else specific to your app or environment. Just with the code from above I cannot reproduce it. Test works ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

*someMethod* returns an observable and the *transform* method of the Pipe returns the call of this method. That is still an observable and cannot be compared to a value.

You can for example subscribe and compare the values there:

```
pipe.transform(null, null).subscribe(res => expect(res).toBe('-'));
```

Comment: I missed one extra intermediate call in my description, beacuse it is not working as you have explained. I edited my question.